# Validating CSRF token generated by rails in express app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, node.js, express, encryption

My app uses rails for the frontend and is an express app on the backend. Is there a way to validate the csrf token generated by rails in an express app?

I've gone through the way in which rails generates the CSRF token and validates it. It stores the real csrf token which is a base64 encoded random hex in session cookie. Post that, it applies a bunch of encryptions including padding some bytes before the encrypted token. The session is encrypted with secret key base.

Intially I thought of getting the real csrf token from session cookie and apply the similar encryption done by rails to validate the token. But this seems to be a tedious task since the session is encrypted with secret key base and express needs to decrypt the detail in session somehow.

Has anyone tried this kind of setup? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What does it mean, "uses rails for the front end"? Rails is server side. So, presumably, you're doing server-to- server. In which case, you could set up some simple keys for application authentication.

Comment: I mean my view layer is in rails. Yeah! that was the one approach I finally narrowed down to.

Comment: I understand what you're attempting to say. But, it's still sort of a nonsense statement. And, the potential lack of understanding it reflects is probably what led you to this poorly-conceived "validating CSRF" notion. It might be worth making sure you really understand how the pieces fit together.